# The mean number of vertices in small connected components of random geometric graphs

Tags: graph-theory, geometry, pr.probability

I place $N$ points on a circular plane of radius $R$, and draw edges to connect points that are less than or equal to some distance $D$ to form a set of graphs or cliques $G_i$.  As a function of $N$, $R$, and $D$, what is the mean number of points, $m_k$, that participate in graphs with $k$ or fewer vertices?

To clarify, the $N$ points are randomly placed on the circular plane with uniform probability across its surface.

Comment: I've rephrased your title to simplify it a bit - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_geometric_graph . Feel free to revert it if I have misread your question.

Comment: @jc Thanks for the new title suggestion, I like it.